# Get the core name in query response Solr

Tags: json, solr

I am using a multicore search in solr, the results are not blended, In order to classify my results I need to get the corename from the response, consider the below response

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "fl": "title,core_name",
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "*:*",
      "_": "1383405269434",
      "wt": "json",
      "rows": "2"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 926,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "title": "Main Page"
      },
      {
        "title": "Albert Einstein"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If I give a parameter say, core_name it should return the core name in every result entry, that is,

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "fl": "title,core_name",
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "*:*",
      "_": "1383405269434",
      "wt": "json",
      "rows": "2"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 926,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "title": "Main Page"
        "core_name": "collection1"
      },
      {
        "title": "Albert Einstein"
        "core_name": "collection1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there any solr variable to get the core name?

Comment: How do you query across several cores? Do you employ the `shards` parameter for this?

Comment: yes.. localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?shards=localhost:8983/solr/collection3,localhost:8983/solr/collection2,localhost:8983/solr/collection1&q=einstein&wt=json&fl=title,id,wikitype,text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using shards, you can add the DocTransformer `[shard]` as query field within the `fl` parameter. The brackets around shard are mandatory and will also occur in the response. This DocTransformer only works, when the shards parameter is present.

To do so you would need to alter your query like this

`localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?shards=localhost:8983/solr/collection3,lo‌​calhost:8983/solr/collection2,localhost:8983/solr/collection1&q=*:*&wt=json&‌​fl=title,[shard]`

This will get you a response like this

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "fl": "title,[shard]",
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "*:*",
      "_": "1383405269434",
      "wt": "json",
      "rows": "2"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 926,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "title": "Main Page"
        "[shard]": "localhost:8983/solr/collection1"
      },
      {
        "title": "Albert Einstein"
        "[shard]": "localhost:8983/solr/collection1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Further reading

- http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#Transformers
- http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DocTransformers